# ggplot2 in R: some variables have multiple groupings

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot odds ratios, but running into an issue because some of my variables have more than one group. As an example, CatA and CatC have one group ("S1"), but CatB and CatD have two groups ("S1" and "S2").

```
dfex = data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                  Category = c("CatA", "CatB", "CatB", "CatC", "CatD", "CatD"),
                  Grouping = c("S1", "S1", "S2", "S1", "S1", "S1"),
                  Odds = c(2.4, 3, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 1.7),
                  CILow = c(1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.1, 0.8),
                  CIHigh = c(4.5, 4.6, 7.9, 5, 5.9, 3.7)
)

ggplot(dfex, aes(x = Odds, y = Category)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), size = .25, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = CIHigh, xmin = CILow), size = .5, height = 
                   .2, color = 'gray50') +
  geom_point(size = 3.5) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,7,1) ) +
  coord_trans(x = 'log10') +
  ylab('') +
  xlab('Odds ratio')
```

[image: odds ratio with overlapping groups for some variables]

I'm looking for a way to including the Grouping variable so that the name ("S1" or "S2") appears and also that the different groups in CatB and CatD be slightly offset so you could see both.

Less important, is there a simple way to have CatA at the top, to match the order of the data frame, without setting a new order for the factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way of doing is to "facet" your plot:

```r
ggplot(dfex, aes(x = Odds, y = Grouping))+
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = CIHigh, xmin = CILow), size = .5, height = 
                   .2, color = 'gray50') +
  geom_point(size = 3.5) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,7,1) ) +
  coord_trans(x = 'log10') +
  ylab('') +
  xlab('Odds ratio')+
  facet_grid(Category~., switch = "y", scales = "free_y")+
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 180),
        strip.background.y = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(-1, "lines"))
```

[image]

An alternative solution is to use `interaction` to group your y values with both `Category` and `Grouping`.

You can also pass `reorder` function in each of them if you don't want to reorder factors before the use of `ggplot`:

```r
ggplot(dfex, aes(x = Odds, 
                 y = interaction( reorder(Category, desc(Category)), reorder(Grouping,desc(Grouping)))))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), size = .25, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = CIHigh, xmin = CILow), size = .5, height = 
                          .2, color = 'gray50') +
  geom_point(size = 3.5) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,7,1) ) +
  coord_trans(x = 'log10') +
  ylab('') +
  xlab('Odds ratio')
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

---

**Update with `ggplot2` v3.3.0**

Minor tweaks to get the first solution working `ggplot2` v3.3.0
is to replace:

```r
strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 180),
```

with

```r
strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
```

Comment: Yes - thanks! The clues get me most of the way there. I'm hitting this error (Error in (function (el, elname)  :  "strip.text.y.left" is not a valid theme element name") but I can work around it. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome ;). Maybe try to use `strip.text.y` instead. What versions of `ggplot2` are you using ?

Comment: Seems like I'm using ‘3.2.1’

Comment: I'm using `ggplot2 3.3.0`. does it work if you are using `strip.text.y` ?

Comment: I checked on an naother computer with `ggplot2 3.2.1`, I edited my answer. It should work now. Let me know

Comment: Almost there! Can the "grouping" label be to the right of the variables? ggplot(dfex, aes(x = Odds, y = Grouping)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), size = .25, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = CIHigh, xmin = CILow), size = .5, height = 
                   .2, color = 'gray50') +
  geom_point(size = 3.5) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,7,1) ) +
  coord_trans(x = 'log10') +
  ylab('') +
  facet_grid(Category ~., switch = "y", scales = "free_y") + 
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 180))

Comment: It is already on the right now ? grouping are S1 and S2 ? or are you talking about right of the plot ?

Comment: S1 and S2 to the right of CatA, CatB, etc. but still on the left side of the plot.

Comment: You mis-copy/paste my answer. There is more function to pass in `theme`. You need to `strip.placement`, ...